# Dynamically Writing in generator template SCSS file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, generator, thor

I'm trying to create my own generator in rails for my standard set up of assets for the pipeline.  I've been following [Ryan Bates Railscast on the generators](http://railscasts.com/episodes/218-making-generators-in-rails-3?view=comments)

He explains how to add dynamic code the html.erb files but I tried to do something similar in scss file and it simply outputs the tags:

```
<% if options.add %>
//Some optional code here
@import "add.css.scss";
<% end %>
```

But instead of executing it when I call create_template it just adds the code into the template.  I've tried calling the file .scss.erb but no joy with that either?

Any ideas on how I might tweak the files to make the if statement work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<%- if options.add -%>`